# Can the growth of a group be bounded concretely when the group is of subexponential growth?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

When talking about the growth of a group, the cases of exponential and polynomial growth are described by concrete bounds on the growth function, however, this is not the case for intermediate growth (or at least, not that I know), so my question is the following:

Let $G$ be finitely generated group of subexponential growth, meaning that there is a symmetric, finite, generating set $S$ containing the identity and such that $\lim |S^n|^{1/n}=1$.

Does this implies that we can bound the growth of $S$ by $|S^n|\leq C\exp(bn^a)$, for appropiate constants $C>0,b>0,0<a<1$? If not, what about other types of bounds?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For specific groups one can prove specific bounds. For a general definition, the word "concrete" is meaningless.

Comment: The question seems reasonable to me. For example, for the Grigorchuk group, Grigorchuk prove that the growth $\beta(n)$ with the standard generating set satisfies $e^{\sqrt{n}} < \beta(n) < e^{n^\theta}$ with $\theta = \log_{32}(31)$, and the value of $\theta$ has been decreased by Bartholdi. "Topics in Geometric Group Theory" by Pierre de la Harpe is a good source for basic information on growth.

Comment: @MoisheKohan the question might be badly worded, but it still makes sense. Is it true that for all groups with sub-exponential growth, the growth is $O(\exp(n^a))$ for some $a < 1$?

Comment: @DerekHolt: That would be an open problem. Such upper bound holds in all known examples.